# How to POST multipartfile from springboot to jersey using the spring rest template?

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, spring-jersey

How can I use spring rest template to POST MultipartFile to a Jersey Endpoint that takes the input as MesssageContext? Do I need to convert the MultipartFile in a format acceptable by the MessageContext of Jersey?

Here is the Jersey endpoint that i need to hit.

```
@Path("/api/{projectid}/issues/{issueid}/attachments")
public IssueAttachmentDTO uploadIssueAttachment(@PathParam(PATH_PARAM_PROJECT_ID) Long projectId, @PathParam(PATH_PARAM_ISSUE_ID) String issueId,
                                                @Context MessageContext messageContext) throws IOException {}
```

P.S. I am creating a Springboot layer over the Jersey REST API. I don't have much knowledge about Jersey.